# How can i save a file that i create into a path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I´m developing a school project where i need to export a html table into a csv file, and when i click in a button i need to save that file into a path like `C:\csvfolder` in the server machine using asp net c#,

The code i use to draw the table and write the table is the following:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("tabela.csv"))
{
using(var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(file,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:95%" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width:"30%">
                        Ap_Name
                    @{
                       file.Write("ApName");
                       file.Write(";");
                    }  
                    </th>
                    @{var u = Model.Inicial;
                      var ultimoap = 0;                   
                    }
                    @while( u<=Model.Final)
                    {
                        <th>
                            @u.ToString("MM/yyyy")
                        </th>
                       file.Write(u.ToString("MM/yyyy"));
                       file.Write(";");
                        u =u.AddMonths(1);
                    }

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        
        

            @for(int y = 0; y<Model.Aps.Count; y++)
            {
                file.WriteLine();
                var dadosap = Model.dados2.Where(s => s.ap_id == Model.Aps[y].ap_id).ToList();
                <tr></tr>
                <td style="width:30%">
                    @Model.Aps[y].ap_name
                </td>
                file.Write(Model.Aps[y].ap_name);
                file.Write(";");
                u = Model.Inicial;
                while( u.Date<=Model.Final.Date)
                {
                    var NumAcesso = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i<dadosap.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if(dadosap[i].MES == u.Month && dadosap[i].year == u.Year)
                        {
                            NumAcesso = dadosap[i].numeroAcessos;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           NumAcesso =NumAcesso; 
                        }    
                    }
                        <th> 
                              @NumAcesso
                        </th>
                        file.Write(NumAcesso);
                        file.Write(";");
                    u = u.AddMonths(1);
            }
            }        
                </tbody>
                </table>
}
}
```

I has thinking on one way to save that file inside a path when i click in the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"  id="ExportToExcel" OnClick="ExportToexcel_Click" value="Export To Excel" ></button>
```

EDIT:I was thinking and i understand that i was thinking in the wrong way.
Now I realized that what i really want, i have the file save in the project folder, and i want that when i click in one button i want to download that file to the client machine.How can i do that?

Comment: Note that ASP.NET code runs on the _server_, so your code should be able to write a file to the _server_ provided the user it runs as has permissions, but it can't write to the _client_. The best you can do is create a download link and let the client choose where to save the file.

Comment: @DStanley when i click in the button I want to saves the file in the server machine in that path C:\csvfolder.

Comment: So just do `new StreamWriter("C:\csvfolder\tabela.csv")`. That should work as long as the user has write access to that folder.  You should probably separate your CSV writing code from the table generation code into separate functions.

Comment: Could you please share your controller details for this request and other deatils.

Comment: I could solve my problem just by using a method public fileresult that sends the file to the user machine with no problem. Im posting a answer to explain how i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search i find out that exists a method `FileResult` that returns a file and just like that i solve my problem.

```
[HttpPost]
        public FileResult PessoasCOunt(dadosPassar dp)
        {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         string filename = dp.AcessoVisita + dp.Inicial.ToString() + "_" + dp.Final.ToString() + ".csv";
         return File(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", filename);
        }
```

And using that i could solve my problem with no problem.